# get DBPedia Live latest data

Tags: sparql, rdf, wikipedia, dbpedia

I have a working query on DBPedia-live that is querying Microsoft's revenue.

```
PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
PREFIX dbr: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>
PREFIX dbp: <http://dbpedia.org/property/>
PREFIX foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>

SELECT DISTINCT ?wikipediaLink ?organisationName    ?revenue   where {
 ?organisation foaf:isPrimaryTopicOf ?wikipediaLink .
 OPTIONAL { ?organisation foaf:name ?organisationName . }
 OPTIONAL {  ?organisation dbp:revenue ?revenue .  }
 FILTER (str(?wikipediaLink) = "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft")  
}
```

This query returns 4 rows:

```
wikipediaLink   organisationName    revenue
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft  "Microsoft Corporation"@en  "US$ 77.85 billion"@en
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft  "Microsoft Corporation"@en  "US$ 93.58 billion"@en
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft  "Microsoft Corporation"@en  "US$ 86.83 billion"@en
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft  "Microsoft Corporation"@en  "9.358E10"^^<http://dbpedia.org/datatype/usDollar>
```

The value currently present on Wikipedia is `US$ 93.58 billion (2015)` , the 2nd row returned.

Is there a way of knowing the time modified for each row, or add some ordering to the returned set?

Comment: I don't think so, because the value is just a literal value. That means, there is no triple with one of the values as subject and e.g. some timepoint as object.

Answer (score 2):

It is better to use dbo:revenue as that is the value extracted from the Microsoft article infobox using DBPedia ontology mappings. It is unclear where those other dbp:revenue values come from because they do not appear in the current version of the [wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft).

DBPedia does not have information about when the value was changed or what year it refers to. You could extract this information from Wikipedia by (a) examining edit history (too see when the value was changed) and (b) by extracting the year from the relevant Wikipedia infobox property + looking up the reference mentioned there.

Ideally, this information would be present in Wikidata (accessible via SPARQL) but currently [Microsoft "page" at Wikidata](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q2283)  does not contain financial information.